Is consciousness "what the introspective faculty measures"?
For the purposes of this question, the "introspective faculty" is a particular subsystem of the brain that is capable of analyzing other subsystems of the brain and emitting judgments like, "I see a brown cow," "I am happy," "The rabbit feels soft." Each such judgment describes some aspect of what the rest of the brain is processing.
Is consciousness the thing that is measured by the introspective faculty?
By analogy, we might define temperature to be the thing that a thermometer measures. Note that the thermometer does not actually need to take a measurement for there to be a temperature. But rather, we would say that a certain object is at 15 C if and only if it has the capacity to induce a reading of 15 C on a thermometer, if that thermometer were applied to it, even though in fact it might not be.
In the same sense, the introspective faculty need not be active and need not emit a judgment, "I am aware of X," for the person to be aware of X. Rather, the person is aware of X if they are in a mental state that has the capacity to induce the introspective faculty to emit that judgment, if the introspective faculty were applied to the question of whether they are aware of X, even though in fact it might not be applied.
The judgment is a thought produced by the introspective faculty, not a verbal utterance, thereby sidestepping the issue of a person lying about what they perceive.
There is a question over whether the introspective faculty can ever be wrong. If so, then it would not be enough to emit the judgment, "I am aware of X," because the faculty might a moment later realize, "Oh, actually I'm not really aware of X." In this case, the measurement we would be interested in, for the purposes of defining consciousness, is the eventual judgment of the faculty, which might be different from the initial judgment. In the same sense, if we apply a thermometer to an object and immediately see the reading 20 C, this does not mean the object's temperature is actually 20 C, because we need to let the thermometer settle to an eventual, final reading (which might be, say, 15 C).

I am guessing it "measures" only one aspect. SEP lists six types of conscious states. Dennett's "narrative consciousness" might be what "introspective faculty measures" almost by definition, if I get it right, but that leaves out much of what typically goes under the label of "consciousness". And introspection is a pretty bad thermometer, even eventually. We should certainly take its readings into account, but not as a basis for defining what "consciousness" amounts to.

@Conifold According to that article, Dennett proposes "to equate the person's conscious mental states with those that appear in the stream"; i.e. Dennett proposes the stream as a full explanation of consciousness, not merely one aspect. My approach here differs from Dennett's because I am concerned with the capacity to induce a certain measurement rather than the actual fact of having taken a measurement (appeared in the stream). If the SEP article accurately represents Dennett's approach, it would be like Dennett's saying that an object has a temperature only when measured by a thermometer.

I don't think introspection is a bad thermometer of consciousness. In fact, even though intellectually from a brain-system perspective I think it is possible the introspective faculty could be wrong, I am having trouble imagining that really happening from a subjective perspective. If I introspect and think I am aware of X, how could I be wrong? Even if I am "mistaken," the mistake itself seems to automatically be a kind of awareness of X.

"Whatever is going to seem right to me is right. And that only means that here we can't talk about “right”", Wittgenstein. A thermometer that reads what one feels like reading is a really bad thermometer. See also Irvine's survey:"Analysing the steps required to use either ‘bottom-up’ bootstrapping methods or comparative techniques for validating introspective procedures or evidence shows that there are a number of reasons why introspective evidence cannot carry significant justificatory weight."

@Conifold Wittgenstein was wrong about a lot of things, including that. There is not only what seems right in the moment; there is also what seems right after considering things more thoroughly, and the latter is superior to the former, and what is objectively right derives from the latter. Also my approach in this question is from the external perspective, analyzing the introspective faculty from outside as a brain system akin to any other physical system. That's not the same as relying on subjective evidence (which can also be valid).
